# Ne & yone purposes

Tags: grammar, particles

> それは最近話題の本ですね.

> その 会社は 欧米に 進出しているよね。

How would each of these sentences fit in a conversation? Ne & yone are very nuanced so surrounding context would help me understand their purposes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept expressed by 「ね」 and 「よね」 are similar, they're both used

- When You Seek the Listeners’ Agreement
- When You Seek the Listeners’ Confirmation

[Sentence Ending Particles: ね, よ, and よね](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/sentence-ending-particles/)

But, there's surely some difference:

**意味は「ね」に近い。確認（聞き手に直接関係することや、聞き手のほうが確かな情報を持っていると思うことについて、確認を求める）（「ね」を使う時より、自分の意見、記憶が不確かな時）**

Basically, 「よね」is used instead of 「ね」

- When you lack confidence in your own opinions or judgments
- Never use 「よね」 when you are talking to superiors or people who are not too close

As for your question,

> それは最近話題の本ですね.

Might be used when you and your close friends are shopping and occasionally pick up a book which is being discussed a lot lately, and you are sure that it is 「最近話題の本」, and you are **Seeking the Listeners’ Agreement or Confirmation**.

As for

> その 会社は 欧米に 進出しているよね。

You and your close friend are talking about a 「会社」, and you think it's 欧米に 進出している now, but **you are not quite sure about it**, so you add 「よね」 to 確認, ask for confirmation.